# How to manually set the Daylight Saving (DST) shift date in Java

Tags: java, dst

My country changed the the Daylight Saving shift date from "October 21" to "November 4" and we need to apply this in our back-end.

The appropriate solution is to update the Operating System configuration, but we have restrictions to do so (legacy dependencies). We are looking for a workaround.

Is it possible to use code and change the DST shift date programmatically?

```
GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar();
gc.setTimeInMillis(0);
gc.set(2018, Calendar.OCTOBER, 21, 0, 0, 0);
gc.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Brazil/East"));
XMLGregorianCalendar xml = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(gc);
System.out.println("XML Date: " + xml.toString());
```

Output must be `-03:00`:

```
XML Date: 2018-10-21T01:00:00.000-02:00
```

Comment: If all else fails, you can write your own logic for this.

Comment: By "OS configuration", you mean server's or JRE's timezone data (tzdata: https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tzdata-versions-138805.html)

Comment: @everton I guess my understanding that Java would take the DST shift date from the Operating System is incorrect?

Comment: @BonanzaOne yes, it's incorrect... what governs that is tzdata, which you need to keep updated with new changes, as shown perfectly by BasilBourque's answer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## OS irrelevent

Your operating system configuration is irrelevant. Most Java implementations by default pick up their initial default time zone from the host OS upon launch. But the *definition* of the time zones is stored *within* the Java implementation.

## Java time zone updater

So you need to update the time zone definitions within your Java implementation. Most implementations use the [*tz database*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database) also known as *tzdata*.

For the Oracle-branded Java implementation, Oracle provides the [*Timezone Updater Tool*](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tzupdater-readme-136440.html). That landing page has an as-of date of 2018-08, so perhaps your time zone’s changes have been included. But I suggest you investigate more closely to verify.

For other implementations, check with the vendor. They may have provided an updated version of the JVM to include the fresh tzdata. Or perhaps they too provide an updater tool. Or perhaps you can replace the tzdata file manually.

## Avoid mangling zone with code

I strongly suggest you avoid trying to make artificial adjustments to the offset yourself in code. **You will likely get it wrong.** Date-time work in surprisingly tricky and confusing.

But if you insist, firstly avoid the terrible old legacy date-time classes such as [`GregorianCalendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html) & `Calendar` & `Date`. These were supplanted years ago by JSR 310. If you must interoperate with old code not yet updated to *java.time*, do your work in the modern classes and then at the end convert via new methods added to the old classes.

Use the modern the *java.time* classes, specifically:

- `Instant` (for a moment in UTC)
- `OffsetDateTime` (for a moment with an offset-from-UTC of hours-minutes-seconds but no time zone)
- `ZonedDateTime` (for a moment in a particular time zone)

You can search Stack Overflow for many existing examples and explanations using these classes. You should focus on [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html), [`ZoneOffset`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/ZoneOffset.html) (rather than [`ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html)), and [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) since you must avoid `ZonedDateTime` if your know your *tzdata* file to be outdated.

### Same moment, different wall-clock time

[image]

#### `OffsetDateTime::withOffsetSameInstant​`

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( "2018-10-21T01:00:00.000-02:00" ) ;
ZoneOffset offset = ZoneOffset.ofHours( -3 ) ;
OffsetDateTime odt2 = odt.withOffsetSameInstant​( offset ) ;  // Same moment, same point on the timeline, different wall-clock time.
```

> odt.toString(): 2018-10-21T01:00-02:00

> odt2.toString(): 2018-10-21T00:00-03:00

In that example, both `odt` and `odt2` represent the same simultaneous moment, the same point on the timeline. If you extract an [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) (a value in UTC), your results will be the same moment. Only their wall-clock time is different.

```
Instant instant1 = odt.toInstant() ;  // Adjust to UTC.
Instant instant2 = odt2.toInstant() ;
boolean sameMoment = instant1.equals( instant2 ) ;
```

> instant1.toString(): 2018-10-21T03:00:00Z

> instant2.toString(): 2018-10-21T03:00:00Z

> sameMoment = true

The `Z` on the end means UTC, an offset-from-UTC of zero, `+00:00`. The `Z` is pronounced “Zulu”. Defined by the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard.

### Different moment, same wall-clock time

[image]

#### `OffsetDateTime::withOffsetSameLocal​`

In contrast, you may want to force the time-of-day thereby representing a *different* moment. For that, use [`withOffsetSameLocal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html#withOffsetSameLocal(java.time.ZoneOffset)) method. Be very aware that you are **changing the meaning of data**, you are moving to another point on the timeline.

```
OffsetDateTime differentMomentButSameTimeOfDay = odt. withOffsetSameLocal( offset ) ;
```

> differentMomentButSameTimeOfDay.toString(): 2018-10-21T01:00-03:00

Extract the instant to see we have a different moment.

```
Instant differentInstant = differentMomentButSameTimeOfDay.toInstant() ;
```

> differentInstant.toString(): 2018-10-21T04:00:00Z

Notice the 4 AM UTC versus 3 AM UTC seen above. This moment here occurs an hour after the moment above. Two different points on the timeline.

Do not attempt this work until you fully comprehend the concept of points on the timeline, and changing between points being entirely different than adjusting offsets. Practice extensively before doing real work. Half-hearted guessing will land you in a world of hurt and headache.

And, as I suggested above, your time would be much better spent installing updated *tzdata* files rather than hacking these offsets.

### Live code

See all the code above [run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/P5IWWJ).

## Update *tzdata* everywhere

For best results, you should be updating the *tzdata* (or equivalent) in all these various places:

- Your operating systems
- Your JVMs
- Your database engines, such as [*Postgres*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL)
- Any libraries bundling their own time zone info (ex: [*Joda-Time*](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/))

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - [**Java 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) brought some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android (26+) bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the process of [*API desugaring*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring) brings a [subset of the *java.time*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) functionality not originally built into Android.

    - If the desugaring does not offer what you need, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above) to Android. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: Basil this is a great answer. Unfortunately we are running very aged legacy code with Java 6, I'll do my best to fix this with your help.

Comment: @BonanzaOne Reread my Answer, with bullets for Java 6 and *ThreeTen-Backport*.

Comment: Just once I would like to see the question answered as asked, rather than suggesting throwing everything out and starting over.